# filter posts without images or featured image

Tags: multisite, thumbnails, featured-post

I'm using wordpress MU 3.3.1. I want to add a function within a loop that displays only posts with image, or featured image.

please help me on how to filter posts.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
<?php 
    global $post;
    $categories = get_categories('child_of=7694');  
    foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $cat_id = $category->cat_ID;

        $games = get_posts('numberposts=6&orderby=rand&category='.$cat_id);

        if ($games) : ?>

          <div class="single">

            <h1><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat_id); ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></h1>

           <?php foreach ($games as $post) : $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>


              <div class="game_title">

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mabp_description', $single = true); ?>" >

                <?php 

                if ( (strlen($post->post_title) > 10) ) { 

                  echo substr($post->post_title, 0, 10).".."; 

                } 

                else {

                  the_title(); 

                }

                ?>

                </a>

                <br />

                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="thumb_link" rel="bookmark" title="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mabp_description', $single = true); ?>"><?php 
gab_media(array(
        'name' => 'gab_featured',
        'enable_video' => 'true',
        'catch_image' => 'true',
        'enable_thumb' => 'true',
        'resize_type' => 'c', 
        'media_width' => '60', 
        'media_height' => '34', 
        'thumb_align' => 'featured_thumb', 
        'enable_default' => get_option('of_nw_enfea2'),
        'default_name' => 'featured_thumb.jpg'                                  
)); 
?>  

</a>                                   
</div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            <div class="cat_link"><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat_id); ?>">More Games</a></div>

          </div>



        <?php endif; }?>



    </div> <?php // End content div ?>



    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You will want to look into [has_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail), [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). I've written [answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46198/how-to-get-a-variable-number-of-posts-per-post-type-on-the-main-loop/46700#46700) to do this sort of thing a dozen times before. Here's another more [complex approach](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46673/how-do-i-create-a-custom-wordpress-slideshow-plugin/46685#46685) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;

$posts = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` p inner join `wp_posts` i on i.id=p.id and p.post_type='post' and i.post_type='attachment' where i.post_parent=p.id ");
```

Comment: i have put my codes in my question. please can you elaborate your answer using my codes? @Rajeev Vyas